# How can I edit products on website scope?

Tags: magento-1.8, product-edit, scope-switcher

When I edit a product in the admin area of Magento I can select to edit the product for the global scope or for any of the store scopes. I would like to edit the product for a website scope.

Is there some trick/ code/ extension which enabled editing products on the website scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no trick, unfortunately. Magento stores all product data on the store level underneath, so that's why you're only able to edit on the global or store level.

A solution without customization is to make your attributes website scope. That way, when you edit them on one of the store levels under `website A`, the update will apply to all stores under `website A`.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for ;-), but thank you nonetheless.